# Cannot add cli parameters to DataSourceOptions in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

In the typeORM documentation a cli parameter can be added to `DataSourceOptions` according to https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/data-source-options.md. The example I saw on https://typeorm.io/using-cli looks was

```
{
    cli: {
        entitiesDir: "src/entity",
        subscribersDir: "src/subscriber",
        migrationsDir: "src/migration"
    }
}
```

I tried this in my code as follows:

```
let dataSource = new DataSource(
  {
        type: 'postgres',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        database: 'website',
        username: 'test',
        password: 'test',
        logging: true,
        synchronize: false,
        entities: [User, Posts],
        cli: {
            entitiesDir: "src/entity",
            subscribersDir: "src/subscriber",
            migrationsDir: "src/migration"
        }
  })
```

However I get the following error:
Argument of type `'{ type: "postgres"; host: string; port: number; database: string; username: string; password: string; logging: true; synchronize: false; entities: (typeof User | typeof Wallet)[]; cli: { entitiesDir: string; subscribersDir: string; migrationsDir: string; }; }'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'DataSourceOptions'`.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and `'cli'` does not exist in type `'PostgresConnectionOptions'.ts`(2345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. To solve this issue, you can simply remove the **cli** key from the *Datasource* options and specify the path when creating a new migration

```
typeorm migration:create -n UrlMigration -d src/migrations
```

-d option is used to specify the directory where your migration will be created

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ormconfig.ts"
}
```

***NB :** Replace ormconfig.ts with your **datasource filename***

refer to [TypeORM CLI help](https://typeorm.io/using-cli)

Note: entities, migrations and subscribers can be added to the datasource options in the folowing way:

```
// ormconfig.ts

export const datasource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  database: "database",
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  entities: [EntityA, EntityB, EntityC],
  migrations: [__dirname + "/migrations/*{.js,.ts}"],
  subscribers: [],
})
```

Comment: Thank you! The documentation on this is opaque to say the least.

Comment: If typeorm is not installed globally, one can do `npm/yarn typeorm migration:create etc.`

Comment: Typeorm changed from calling it ormconfig.ts to datasource.ts typically

Answer (score 1):

**TypeORM** and **TypeORM CLI** not works perfectly after **0.3.0**. I had the same problem, so I advice you to downgrade to version **0.2**

Comment: same problem. switched to version 0.2, everything worked without errors

Answer (score 1):

also, I had a similar issue
typeorm version: 0.3.7

what I did:

1. I created in src/config/ormconfig-migrations.ts

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

const configMigration = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'mediumclone',
  password: 'qwerty',
  database: 'mediumclone',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
});

export default configMigration;
```

in src/comfig/ormconfig.ts

```
import { DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

const config: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'mediumclone',
  password: 'qwerty',
  database: 'mediumclone',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
};

export default config;
```

i had separeted, because ormconfig i use for connect db on my app, a ormconfig-migrations.ts - l use to migrations

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from '@app/app.controller';
import { AppService } from '@app/app.service';
import { TagModule } from '@app/tag/tag.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import ormconfig from '@app/config/ormconfig';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig), TagModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2. in package.json i added:

```
"scripts": {
     "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d src/config/ormconfig-migrations.ts",
     "db:drop": "yarn run typeorm schema:drop"
}
```

3. in a terminal:

```
yarn run db:drop
```

but i have a problem with:

```
yarn run typeorm migration:generate -n
```

who did it resolve, please if you resolve this, let know

i hope that with npm other people will not have a problems
i hope it helps to someone

Answer (score 0):

(15/08/2022) Hi!. I update typeorm to 0.3.7, and typeorm is working with DataSource (in the typeorm web page tutorial is called data-source.ts) instead of ormconfig.ts...  and i realized that

> cli: {
> entitiesDir: "src/entity",
> subscribersDir: "src/subscriber",
> migrationsDir: "src/migration"
> }

does not work. But following these steps might help you:

1-- Add these lines in your scripts of your packege.json

> "scripts": {
> ...
> "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
> "typeorm_src": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d src/data-source.ts"
> }

"src/data-source.ts" is where you have your database info...

- (in case of generate migrations)
  In your terminal located in your root directory, you have to write this line

> npm run typeorm_src migration:generate src/migrations/nameOfMyMigration

- (in case of only create migrations wich is a empty file)
  In your terminal located in your root directory, you have to write this line

> npm run typeorm migration:create src/migrations/nameOfMyMigration

- In both cases the lines are going to generate a file (in src/migrations/nameOfMyMigration) with the migrations to do and with the name {timestamp}-nameOfMyMigration.ts, after the creation of that file, execute this line

> npm run typeorm_src migration:run

it is going to make the migrations in your database previously generated in your {timestamp}-nameOfMyMigration.ts.

SOURCE: https://typeorm.io/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u have `type`, in your data source options
forexample

```
 import { DataSource } from "typeorm"

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({

    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "test",
    logging: true,
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [],
    subscribers: [],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `yarn run typeorm migration:generate -n` I solved with add path to your migration with name, like this:

```
yarn run typeorm migration:generate ./src/db/migrations/NameMyMigration
```